# How to specify external C++ source folders for Android NDK with Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I want to add some C++ source files to my Android Studio project that are not in the project tree. I'm new to Gradle, and tried to research this as much as possible. From what I read, the following build.gradle file should work, but it doesn't. The bit about `jni.sourceDirs` came from this post: http://www.shaneenishry.com/blog/2014/08/17/ndk-with-android-studio/

Is this the right approach?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mycompany.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 22

        ndk {
            moduleName "mymodule"
            ldLibs "log"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    sourceSets.main {
        jni.srcDirs '../external/source/dir'
    }
}
```

Comment: I've had a bad time when re-specifying the srcDirs, but one thing that I believe worked for me was using an absolute path (well, relative to the projectDirs) - the reason is that you're overwriting that srcDirs attribute - so you can't assume the directory starts where you think

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at my article about this:
http://www.sureshjoshi.com/mobile/android-ndk-in-android-studio-with-swig/

> There are two things you need to know here. By default, if you have
>   external libs that you want loaded into the Android application, they
>   are looked for in the (module)/src/main/jniLibs. You can change this
>   by using setting sourceSets.main.jniLibs.srcDirs in your module’s
>   build.gradle. You’ll need a subdirectory with libraries for each
>   architecture you’re targeting (e.g. x86, arm, mips, arm64-v8a, etc…)
>
> The code you want to be compiled by default by the NDK toolchain will
>   be located in (module)/src/main/jni and similarly to above, you can
>   change it by setting sourceSets.main.jni.srcDirs in your module’s
>   build.gradle

And a sample Gradle file from that page:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sureshjoshi.android.ndkexample"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        ndk {
            moduleName "SeePlusPlus" // Name of C++ module (i.e. libSeePlusPlus)
            cFlags "-std=c++11 -fexceptions" // Add provisions to allow C++11 functionality
            stl "gnustl_shared" // Which STL library to use: gnustl or stlport
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Also, when specifying external to the /jni directory, try using the full build path (using one of the macros, eg):

```
'${project.buildDir}/../../thirdParty/blah/blah/'
```

Comment: most of your answer does not directly address my question, but thanks for the bit about the macro. i did get it working. my problem was that the relative path was wrong, and the macro helped me fix that.

Comment: Use ndk.cFlags (capital ndk.CFlags in 0.4 exp) to specify library paths with: -I${project.buildDir}/../src/main/jni/inc". Use the ldFlags for any libraries. Mine are like so

Answer (score 1):

Currently, and using 'gradle-experimental:0.7.3' this definition is changed a bit. 
With this new version the object to be set as 'srcDirs' must be an iterable object, so multiple c++ source paths can be included.

In the next example, there are two folders included, the current main folder ('src/main/jni'), and a second one ('../../common') out of the android project folder tree:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion  23
        buildToolsVersion  "23.0.2"
        defaultConfig.with {
            applicationId  "com.test.androidTest"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel  21
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel  23
            versionCode = 1
            versionName = "1.0"
       }
    }

    android.ndk {
        moduleName = "jni_lib_name"
        platformVersion = 9
        toolchain "gcc"
        debuggable true
        cppFlags.add("-fexceptions")
        cppFlags.add("-std=c++14")

        ....
    }

    android {
        sources {
            main {
                jni {
                    source {
                        srcDirs = ["src/main/jni".toString(), "../../common".toString()]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, you get the idea:

```
android.ndk {
    moduleName = "mydemo"

    //Specify a library relative to this project path
    CFlags.add('-I' + String.valueOf(project.buildDir) + '/../my/inc/path')

    //or CPP
    cppFlags.add('-I' + String.valueOf(project.buildDir) + '/../my/inc/path')

    //Linker works the same way
    ldFlags.add("-L/custom/lib/path")
    ldLibs.addAll(["log", "GLESv2", "myCustomLibrary"])
}
```